# Scale an image with c++ / MFC

Tags: c++, image, mfc

I’m trying to create a preview for “SMB” file, in which it’s a sort of image that can be generated with AutoCAD, I must load this image into a `CRect` that has 100 width and 100 height.
However this image have a high resolution, and it contains a very small fish drawn in it.
When the preview is created only white space is shown. In other cases where the image has a reasonable size its shown correctly.

I would like to know how to scale an image, in a way where I can zoom in the center of the image and lose the rest, just to keep it in the limits of the `CRect` object in which are 100 width and 100 height.

Here is the code I’m currently using :

```
HBITMAP hBitmap;
hBitmap = CreateDIBitmap(pDc->m_hDC, 
                        &EnteteSymb.BitmapInfoHeader,                           
                        (LONG)CBM_INIT, 
                        EnteteSymb.BitmapData,
                        (LPBITMAPINFO)&EnteteSymb.BitmapInfoHeader, 
                        DIB_RGB_COLORS);
CDC DCMem;
DCMem.CreateCompatibleDC(pDc);
DCMem.SelectObject(hBitmap);

int X       = Rect.left + MARGES_X;
int Y       = Rect.top  + MARGES_Y;
int Width   = Rect.right - Rect.left - ( 2 * MARGES_X );
int Height  = ( Rect.bottom ) - ( Rect.top + MARGES_Y ) - 1;

pDc->StretchBlt( X, Y, Width, Height, &DCMem, 0, 0, 100, 100,  SRCCOPY);

DCMem.DeleteDC();
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you offset a rectangle you have to change both `Rect.left` and `Rect.right`, same with `::top` and `::bottom`. You can use `OffsetRect` or `MoveToXY`.

If `Rect` is the destination rectangle of width and height `100`, use the following:

```
int margin_x = 10;
int margin_y = 10;
CRect Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
Rect.MoveToXY(margin_x, margin_y);
```

Use `GetObject` to find the dimension of the `source` rectangle:

```
BITMAP bm;
GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
CRect source(0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight);
```

Make sure `source` is greater than `destination` rectangle. Then use `BitBlt` for one to one mapping.

```
if(source.Width() > Rect.Width() && source.Height() > Rect.Height())
{
    int x = (source.Width() - Rect.Width()) / 2;
    int y = (source.Height() - Rect.Height()) / 2;
    dc.BitBlt(Rect.left, Rect.top, Rect.Width(), Rect.Height(), &memdc, x, y, SRCCOPY);
}
```

`StretchBlt` is usually used to fit the whole image in to a destination rectangle. If you were to use `StretchBlt` the function would look as follows:

```
dc.StretchBlt(Rect.left, Rect.top, Rect.Width(), Rect.Height(), 
    &memdc, x, y, Rect.Width(), Rect.Height(), SRCCOPY);
```

Read more about [`BitBlt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370(v=vs.85).aspx) and `StretchBlt` and see description of destination and source rectangle.